# NSDateFormatter setting year wrong

Tags: objective-c

I have some code that takes a data and converts it to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS which you can see below.

It is currently 7:29 pm on 12/13/2013 on the east coast where im at.  When i run the code below the year is showing as 2014.  Why is that?  it should be 2013.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"YMMddHHmmss"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"date test" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[view show];
```

Comment: Don't use capital "Y".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NSDateFormatter, "Y" and "y" specify different kinds of year that may start on different days. You want "y".

From [the NSDateFormatter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year
>   whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO
>   year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same
>   number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the
>   calendar year.